# how to set a table mysql column to hijri shamsi, arabic date

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the dbtest.table_t

```
id     name     year
1      abc      2014
```

---

did trigger so the column year will take default current year base on system time now.

```
TRIGGER `db_test`.`ins_year`
BEFORE INSERT ON `dbtest`.`table_t`
FOR EACH ROW
set new.year = year(now())$$

insert into table_t (`id`,`name`) value (`2`,`def`);
```

the result will be

```
id     name    year
2      def     2014   // as 2014 is current year of the system it will take default.
```

but i want this in hijri shamsi(arabic celender) as for exampe now is the year 1393 
how i can set like this.

```
id     name      year
1      abc       1392
2      def       1392
3      efg       1392
```

As I have enter the up records in 1392 but now is 1393 according to the system year.
When I insert:

```
insert into table_t (`id`,`name`) value (`4`,`hij`)
```

Result should set the

```
id     name      year
4      hij       1393
```

How to make the mysql database to select year based on Hijri shamsi?

If in PHP I do `echo $date = date("Y");` it will show me now year(2014).
How I can echo that show me Hijri shamsi (1393) in PHP?

Also how I can translate my up trigger to have result in Hijri shamsi?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the PHP manuel for calendar functions, in the user contributed notes section there is a class for converting the Julian To Hijri, FYI there is no official support for Hijri calendar in the PHP API or MySQL ! link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php#54234